# No keyword with name 'Select Window' found

Tags: robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Selenium2Library

*** Variable ***
${handles}

*** Test Case ***
Testing
    open browser    https://www.reddit.com/   chrome
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://www.google.com')
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')
    Execute Javascript    window.open('https://images.google.com')

    ${handles}=     Get Window Handles

    Set Global Variable     ${handles}
    FOR     ${rowIndex}     IN RANGE    1   18
        Select Window   ${handles}[${rowIndex}]
    END
```

Select Window Statement is not working. Please help.
*I have tried SeleniumLibrary as well. But, I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select Window` was deprecated a long time ago, and finally removed in `SeleniumLibrary` version 5. You should use [Switch Window](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Switch%20Window) instead.

Comment: Thanks Mate. But, Switch Window traverses from each open tab to reach the said tab which is a little time-consuming. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sudarsh: I'm not sure what you mean. When I call `Switch window` to go to a different tab by using the title, it's nearly instantaneous.

Answer (score 0):

I have a set where for some tests I use the 'SeleniumLibrary' and others 'Browser'

https://robotframework-browser.org/

this case you might try the latter.

Answer (score 0):

`Select Window` is now updated to switch window.
You can check this in the robot framework official documents.